# FormattedMessage values chunks using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-intl

I saw this example in the docs:

```html
<FormattedMessage
  id="foo"
  defaultMessage="To buy a shoe, <a>visit our website</a> and <cta>buy a shoe</cta>"
  values={{
    a: chunks => (
      <a
        class="external_link"
        target="_blank"
        href="https://www.example.com/shoe"
      >
        {chunks}
      </a>
    ),
    cta: chunks => <strong class="important">{chunks}</strong>,
  }}
/>
```

but when using typescript, the following error occurs for the chunks functions:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): FormattedMessage', gave the following error.
    Type '(chunks: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Element | Date | null | undefined'.
      Type '(chunks: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Props, context: any): FormattedMessage', gave the following error.
    Type '(chunks: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'string | number | boolean | Element | Date | null | undefined'.
      Type '(chunks: any) => Element' is not assignable to type 'Date'.
```

Is the types for FormattedMessage not accepting functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type string[] will work without any errors.

```
<FormattedMessage
    id="foo"
    defaultMessage="To buy a shoe, <a>visit our website</a> and <cta>buy a shoe</cta>"
    values={{
      a: (chunks: string[]) => (
        <a
          className="external_link"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          href="https://www.example.com/shoe"
        >
          {chunks}
        </a>
      ),
      cta: (chunks: string[]) => (
        <strong className="important">{chunks}</strong>
      )
    }}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

`string[]` didn't work for me but `ReactNode[]` did.  But I had to upgrade to `react-intl` v6.4.2.  (Both `string[]` and `ReactNode[]` failed for me on `react-intl` v5.)

```
<FormattedMessage
    id="foo"
    defaultMessage="To buy a shoe, <a>visit our website</a> and <cta>buy a shoe</cta>"
    values={{
      a: (chunks: ReactNode[]) => (
        <a
          className="external_link"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer"
          href="https://www.example.com/shoe"
        >
          {chunks}
        </a>
      ),
      cta: (chunks: ReactNode[]) => (
        <strong className="important">{chunks}</strong>
      )
    }}
  />
```